# wheel of sun and moon and tutors

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So let's say I have [Wheel of Sun and Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146740) in play and cast a tutor that puts the card I searched for on top of my library. Let's say, [Enlightened Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15355). In what order do things happen in then? Do I put the Enlightened Tutor at the bottom of my library and then shuffle (at which point it probably wouldn't be at the bottom anymore) or do I shuffle and then put the Enlightened Tutor at the bottom?

In either case I assume the enchantment I searched for would go on top at the very end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When casting an instant or sorcery, it goes:

- Announce the spell and pay all costs
- People can respond
- Spell effect happens
- Spell goes to graveyard

So in this case, you'd cast Enlightened Tutor, find the enchantment, shuffle your library and put then enchantment on top, and then try to put Enlightened Tutor in your graveyard. So you have your target on top of your library and Enlightened Tutor on the bottom.